# How to prevent activating Ctrl+Alt+key bindings when pressing R.Alt+key?

Tags: windows, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have one very annoying issue with Eclipse under Windows. The key bindings for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> are activated when I press <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>key</kbd>. This made me viewing the list of key bindings and remove all bindings for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>, which I would find usable, when they wouldn't block inputing characters.

I'm using keyboard mappings, where right conrol is a switch key for national characters. <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> = ę, <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> = ó etc. Eclipse seems not to be compatibile with such keyboard layouts.

Is there any possibility of switching off this behaviour and making Eclipse to use key bindings only with <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, eclipse doesn't differentiate between which CTRL key is used to execute a keybinding.  It's listening for any key pressed with a modifier (CTRL, ALT, etc) in an SWT filter.

If it's not the OS consuming the CTRL and generating the national character then the eclipse keybindings could consume it before your get your correct character.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I've meant Right Alt. There are no known to me keyboard layout bindings distinguishing right and left control.

Comment: The same thing applies, eclipse doesn't currently distinguish between right and left ALT keys.  So if the OS doesn't eat them, eclipse will if it finds a matching key shortcut.

Comment: So, I suppose, eclipse eats before keyboard layout controller :(

Comment: I guess it depends at what level your keyboard mapping software runs ... I thought normally such software inserted itself into the windows key processing buffer